# VirtualBox Snapshots and Details panes keep disappearing

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have a relatively small but persistently annoying issue with VirtualBox Manager. If I activate either the Snapshot pane (Machine Tools -> Snapshots), the Details pane (Machine Tools -> Details) or both, next time I open VirtualBox Manager they are gone. This behavior seems inconsistent, meaning occasionally the panes will be retained and other times they won't.

This behavior started happening recently when I upgraded VirtualBox version to 5.2.32r. The machine host is a Windows 7.

Any ideas as to what might be causing the issue, and how to fix it?

[VirtualBox Manager, Snapshot pane on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Q8h.png)

[VirtualBox Manager, Snapshot pane gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTaW6.png)